# Connection between web parts in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, ssas, sharepoint-designer

I have a couple of questions regarding SharePoint 2007.

1. Is it possible to bind a List View Web Part to SQL Analysis Services using SharePoint configuration?
2. I have two webparts. When clicking one row of a List View Web Part, I want to show a chart in another web part based on the value on the clicked row. How can I achieve this functionality? Is this possible without writing any code, just by configuring?

Comment: You might want to ask these as two separate questions tagged appropriately for best results.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the functionality delivered in [PerformancePoint](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/performancepoint/default.aspx), which comes with a SharePoint E-Cal (although it was originally a separate product). The PPS Dashboard Item Web Part does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: PerformancePoint works pretty well in a SharePoint if they only interact with each other.  But PPS "webparts" do NOT talk to standard SharePoint webparts.  And working around that is not pretty.

Comment: @dmo: You're right. What he'd have to do is do a scorecard with a chart in PPS, rather than using a native ListView in SharePoint.